# Blocked operation in finally in reactor stream

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have following logical flow.

```
public Mono<Response> process(Request request) {
   var existingData = repository.find(request.getId());
   if (existingData != null) {
     if (existingData.getState() != pending) {
       throw new RuntimeException("test");
     }
   } else {
     existingData = repository.save(convertToData(request));
   }
   
   try {
     var response = hitAPI(existingData);
   } catch(ServerException serverException) {
     log.error("");
     throw serverException;
   } finally {
     repository.save(existingData);
   }
   
   return convertToResponse(existingData, response);
}
```

I attempted following in my reactor based project (using spring-webflux):

```
repository.find(request.getId())
    .flatMap(existingData -> {if (existingData.getState() != pending) {throw new RuntimeException("test");}})
    .switchIfEmpty(respository.save(convertToData(request)))
    .flaptMap(existingData -> hitAPI(existingData))
    .flatMap(existingData -> convertToResponse(existingData))
    //? how to handle above error?
```

In the above code, operation in `finally` is blocking and needs to be combined. I am stuck how to combine this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using project-reactor you should avoid throwing exceptions. `Mono` and `Flux` already implement the concept of error signals and their handling. Standard operators to use for error handling inside reactor would be:

- `doOnError`: for side-effectful things, like logging
- `onErrorResume`: to supply a new stream that will be subscribed on to by the outer one
- `onErrorMap`: to transform the error itself to another error
- `onErrorContinue`: **do not ever use this one.**

I think a new convenience operator is being added that will be equivalent to `onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.empty())` to terminate the stream on error.

I have modified your code in order to be more idiomatic.

```java
public Mono<Response> process(Request request) {
   return repository.find(request.getId())
      .flatMap(existingData -> {
          if (existingData.getState() != pending) {
              return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("test"));
          } else {
              return repository.save(convertToData(request));
          }
      })
      .flatMap(existingData -> Mono
          .fromCallable(() -> hitAPI(existingData))
          .doOnError(ServerException.class, throwable -> log.error("", throwable))
          .onErrorResume(throwable -> repository.save(existingData)
               .then(Mono.error(throwable)))
          .flatMap(response -> repository.save(existingData)
              .map(existingData -> convertToResponse(existingData, response))))
```

Your `finally` statement is broken up and the logic inside it is replicated in 2 places, the standard flow, and the error flow.

P.S. This code assumes a reactive repository.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that main issue was due to hitAPI is modifying existingData (have non-immutability and side-effect). By refactoring it, it becomes one of the standard use-case.

Comment: I modified hitAPI to return the response (error response if any exception is encountered). Then chaining becomes easier.